# Correctness of this sentence

Tags: syntax, sentence

The original sentence was:

> 運転教官は私に毎日運転するように言いました。
> The driving instructor told me to drive every day.

But I wanted to change it into something more complex or perhaps similar to how a native speaker would say it.

> 運転教官は毎日運転した方がいいように言わせられてくれました。
> The driving instructor told me that I should drive every day.

Is it correct? Or please can some of you tell me how to say it in a more native way?

Thank you in advance! ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original sentence is already perfectly natural, but I'm afraid to say your attempt makes no sense.

言わせられてくれた is a causative-passive form followed by the past form of a donatory subsidiary verb くれた. It would mean "the instructor was (kindly) made (by someone) to say ～", if it means anything. However, the causative-passive meaning ("the instructor was made to say ～") has nothing to do with the intended meaning. Using くれる is not wrong if you are really thankful, but you usually don't need to thank for a simple advice like this.

It's possible rephrase the original sentence by using a simple passive form, like so:

> 運転教官に毎日運転するよう言われました。
> I was told to drive every day by the driving instructor.

But this is no better than the original sentence as far as the naturality is concerned.

Comment: I understood! Your answer was very helpful, thank you!
So, if i wanted to use just the causative-passive form without the donatory subsidiary? 
Like: 運転教官は私に毎日運転するよう言わせられました
In this case it would mean that the fact that the instructor told me to do x, somehow offended me or something, right?

Comment: as for the form 「～ し た 方 が い い 」is it possible to use it within a sentence with「 ～ よ う に 言 い ま す」?
Like in my example from my question, okay the last part is wrong, but what if I wrote:
運転教官は私に毎日運転した方がいいように言いました。

And is it the に particle always mandatory?

Comment: @GabrieleAlongi 毎日運転した方がいいように言いました is ungrammatical. Recheck how to use ように. 毎日運転したほうがいいと言われました is fine.

Comment: Okay! Thank you! ^.^